# Pandas: groupby to list

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like below:

```
id  value   time

1   5   2000
1   6   2000
1   7   2000
1   5   2001
2   3   2000
2   3   2001
2   4   2005
2   5   2005
3   3   2000
3   6   2005
```

My final goal is to have data in a list like below:

```
[[5,6,7],[5]] (this is for id 1 grouped by the id and year)
[[3],[3],[4,5]] (this is for id 2 grouped by the id and year)
[[3],[6]] (same logic as above)
```

I have grouped the data using `df.groupby(['id', 'year'])`. But after that, I am not able to access the groups and get the data in the above format.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `apply(list)`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['id', 'time'])['value'].apply(list)

id  time
1   2000    [5, 6, 7]
    2001          [5]
2   2000          [3]
    2001          [3]
    2005       [4, 5]
3   2000          [3]
    2005          [6]
Name: value, dtype: object
```

If you really want it in the exact format as you displayed, you can then groupby `id` and apply `list` *again*, but this is not efficient, and that format is arguably harder to work with...

```
>>> df.groupby(['id','time'])['value'].apply(list).groupby('id').apply(list).tolist()
[[[5, 6, 7], [5]], [[3], [3], [4, 5]], [[3], [6]]]
```

Comment: Every time I notice myself typing `.apply(...)` I think "You are stepping outside of Pandas". Also because there is a saying: "`apply()` is slow and not vectorized". However, I must start getting used to it. Sometimes it's the best way.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to calculate **the lists for multiple columns**, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [1,1,2,2,2,2,3],
     'B':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
     'C':['x','y','z','x','y','z','x']})

df.groupby('A').agg({'B': list,'C': list})
```

Which will calculate lists of B and C:

```
              B             C
A                            
1        [a, b]        [x, y]
2  [c, d, e, f]  [z, x, y, z]
3           [g]           [x]
```

To get lists for all columns:

```
df.groupby('A').agg(list)
```

To have the lists be sorted:

```
df.groupby('A').agg(sorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 5, 2000],
        [1, 6, 2000],
        [1, 7, 2000],
        [1, 5, 2001],
        [2, 3, 2000],
        [2, 3, 2001],
        [2, 4, 2005],
        [2, 5, 2005],
        [3, 3, 2000],
        [3, 6, 2005]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'value', 'year'])

result = []
for name, group in df.groupby(['id']):
    result.append([g['value'].values.tolist() for _, g in group.groupby(['year'])])

for e in result:
    print(e)
```

**Output**

```
[[5, 6, 7], [5]]
[[3], [3], [4, 5]]
[[3], [6]]
```