# Pandas get all the groups created through ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

[image]

I want to group each passenger id so that I can see all the values from `'from'` and `'to'` columns for each passenger.

I have tried this:

```
flights.groupby(['passengerId','from', 'to']).all()
```

But it shows the wrong results:

[image]

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you replace your image by the plain text dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean "group each passenger id so that I can see all the values". Like sort the DataFrame so they are all together? `groupby` is used for calculations over a window, not (typically) for visual indicators.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
flights = flights.set_index(['passengerId','from', 'to'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to sort the dataframe?

```
flights.sort_values(['passengerId','from', 'to'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your dataset so I just used the passengerId, from and to columns.

```
import pandas as pd
d = { 
'passengerId':[48,94,48],
 'from': ['cg','cg','ts'],
 'to': ['ir','ir','sd']
                        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.groupby(['passengerId','from','to']).apply(list)
print(df)
```

This prints.

```
passengerId from to
48           cg   ir
             ts   sd
94           cg   ir
```

More information can be found here: [Pandas: groupby to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037888/pandas-groupby-to-list).